# Would it be better to post message data or send it through websockets?

Tags: post, websocket, socket.io

I have an app running where a socket connection is constantly maintained (using socket.io). Data that needs to be sent is similar to that which you might see in a chat application. Would it be better to have it sent through POST (essentially, post that data, prevent page redirect, and then return the new page state with websockets), or just send it through websockets? What are the advantages to each?

Answer (score 1):

(You might want to explain what you're trying to accomplish in more detail.  Do you want to implement chat-like functionality).

A WebSocket gives you a TCP-like connection protocol over an HTTP connection.  It's full duplex and lets you push and pull content in both directions.  The connection is initiated from HTTP which "upgrades" the connection type.  It gives you flexibility with some added complexity.  I don't think it works across old HTTP 1.0 proxies.

A simple HTTP POST is more brute force.  Unless you use ajax-ish techniques it pushes data to a web service and responds with a new web page to replace whatever's in your browser.